# classifying images using tensorflow and expo-image-picker

Tags: react-native, tensorflow, expo, mobilenet

I am building react native application (expo cli), and I am using tensor flow js, and mobilenet model to classify images, for images i am using expo-image-picker for picking images,

and I am getting error after executing this line :

```
const response = await fetch(image.uri, {}, { isBinary: true });
```

The error is :

```
[TypeError: Network request failed]
```

and the image.uri is something like this :

```
"file:///data/user/0/host.exp.exponent/cache/ExperienceData/%2540nouragha%252FSmartRecognitionApp/ImageManipulator/90698957-22b1-4e28-a597-479f69a3918c.jpg"
```

Comment: You are not passing in a URL so the request fails.

Comment: i am passing this uri: "file:///data/user/0/host.exp.exponent/cache/ExperienceData/%2540nouragha%252FSmartRecognitionApp/ImageManipulator/90698957-22b1-4e28-a597-479f69a3918c.jpg"